# How do I split a string with backward slashes in from the backward slashes substring using split() of python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string which looks similar to `123456     \\RE1NUM=987` and I have been trying to split it `\\RE1NUM=`.

I have tried `.split("\\RE1NUM=")` and it gives `['123456     \\', '987']`. I believe backward slashes are being interpreted as escape characters.
The final list I need will be `['123456     ', '987']`.

The "string" is actually a line I am reading from a file object. It does work when isolated and tested on string, but fails when used on file's line. (I'll try to recreate this problem on a test file and paste the contents here.)

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce from your example. `print("123456     \\RE1NUM=987".split("\\RE1NUM="))` gives your expected output.

Comment: Why are you asking about forward slashes but none of your examples contain forward slashes? This is a forward slash: `/`.

Comment: I forgot it, fixed the typo now. Guess that's what 24 hrs of constant debugging can do to our :brain: :P

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to use a different editor? cause I have tried to use the python shell in my terminal and it did indeed give me the desired output as follows
[image]

Comment: Yeah it isn't happening when isolated and used on string but my "string" is actually a line from file. I'll try to reproduce with a test file and paste it here for everyone.:)

Comment: waiting for the results, i'll try to help

Answer (score -1):

replit link: https://replit.com/@shivvohra/StackOverflow1?v=1

Code:

```
string = '123456     \\RE1NUM=987'
var = string.replace("\\", " ").split()

first_six_letters = var[0]
last_few_numbers = var[1].split('=')

last_three_letters = last_few_numbers.pop(1)

combined = [first_six_letters, last_three_letters]

print(combined)
```

Output:
['123456', '987']

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90mxY.png)

Answer (score -2):

for example code:

```
string =  "123456     \\RE1NUM=987"
result =  string.split("\\\\RE1NUM=")     
print(result)
```

Comment: 1) Please format your answer properly.  2) Please provide context as to *why* you believe this to be a viable answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).